# заполнение двумерного массива

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с заданием: как записать в двумерным массив значения из двух одномерных массив. Записывать мне надо так: матрица будет размера Nx2 в первом столбике должны содержаться значения из первого одномерного массива, во втором столбике значения из второго одномерного массива.
Фрагмент кода прилагать не вижу смысла, потому что на данный момент мой код состоит из цикла for внутри которого еще один цикл for, это очевидно...

Comment: и да, двумерный массив мною уже был создан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то как то так, но здесь небольшой пример:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
const int n = 5;
int mas[n] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int mas_a[n]= {6,7,8,9,10};
int d_mas[n][2];
for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)
{
     d_mas[i][0] = mas[i];
     d_mas[i][1] = mas_a[i];
     std::cout<<d_mas[i][0]<< " ";
     std::cout<<d_mas[i][1]<< "\n";
}
 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Это-же элементарно, Ватсон.."